# Looping over descending values in Stata using forvalues

Tags: stata

So this works as expected:

```
. forvalues i = 1(1)3 {
  2. di `i'
  3. }
```

> 1
>     2
>     3

And this doesn't:

```
. forvalues i = 3(1)1 {
  2. di `i'
  3. }
           <--- that's an empty line that returns from the above loop.
```

If I want to produce

```
3
2
1
```

do I really need to get this belabored?

```
. forvalues i = 1(1)3 {
  2. di 3+1-`i'
  3. }
```

Why?

Comment: `forv i = 3(-1) 1` Your step is -1 not 1.

Comment: Make that an answer! :)

Comment: You're welcome. Note that even on the most pessimistic reading 3 + 1 can be rewritten as 4.

Comment: @NickCox Natch... of course `k'+1 might be useful also... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your loop should start

```
forv i = 3(-1)1
```

as your step is `-1` not `1`.